# how can I use valgrind to write a wrapper function to test ioctl system call?

Tags: valgrind, ioctl

I don't know how to write it.
For testing the ioctl in  my NIC driver,I must write a wrapper function.But I can't understand the valgrind manual says.
I want to know the PRE(ioctl) and POST(ioctl) function should add my source code or add to the valgrind source code?

I add to my driver source code ,but I can't compile using gcc,which .h file should I #include.

HELP!!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have solved the question.
I should add the PRE and POST code to valgrind source code.

Comment: Good for you that you found the solution you were looking for. Would you mind sharing the details with some example code?